# Numberpart of a string in specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SqlServe and I need to get all rows where a part of the string is within a specific numberRange.

As example I've got in the column uniqueStringID:

- BE09 Mytest
- BE10 Mytest
- CE101 Mytest
- CE300 Mytest

and I want to get all rows where the number within uniqueStringID (the number has to be located before the space) is between (including) 10 and 101

So result would be:

- BE10 Mytest
- CE101 Mytest

My question here is this possible with just SQL or would I need a stored procedure for that? And if the former how would the SQL be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table #t
create table #t(id varchar(100))
insert into #t values('BE09 Mytest'),
('BE10 Mytest'),
('CE101 Mytest'),
('CE300 Mytest'),
('CE450595 Mytest')


select id,cast(substring(id,patindex('%[0-9]%',id),patindex('%[a-z0-9] [a-z]%',id)-1) as int) from #t where cast(substring(id,patindex('%[0-9]%',id),patindex('%[a-z0-9] [a-z]%',id)-1) as int) between 10 and 101
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22262)</kbd>

<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO WITH FEW MORE TEST CASES](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22264)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Hi first Create function in sql server

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

and then use below query to get result

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT uniqueStringID,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(uniqueStringID) AS NumuniqueStringID 
 FROM YourTableName
) a
WHERE NumuniqueStringID >=10 and NumuniqueStringID<=101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to get part with your number for filtering  (in all your examples string in the end is always the same length):

```
select cast(substring(uniqueStringID, 3, len(uniqueStringID)-9) as int)
```